# Estimate the probability $P(X > C\frac{(n-1)^p}{\sqrt{n}})$ for $X\sim N(0,1), C>0, p>1/2$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be brownian motion, let $p>1/2$. I want to show that 
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{B_t}{t^p} \to 0 \quad a.s.$$

Atm I'm trying to show that 
$$\limsup_{t\to \infty} \frac{B_t}{t^p} \to 0 \quad a.s.$$

by applying Borel-Cantelli on the event $A = \limsup_{n \to \infty}A_n, A_n = \{\sup_{n-1\leq t \leq n} B_t > C(n-1)^p \}, C > 0.$
This means I want to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n) < \infty$, which implies $P(A) = 0 \quad a.s. \Rightarrow \limsup_{t\to \infty} \frac{B_t}{t^p} \to 0 \quad a.s.$. By the reflection principle
$$P(\sup_{n-1\leq t \leq n} B_t > C(n-1)^p) \leq P(\sup_{0\leq t \leq n} B_t > C(n-1)^p)$$
$$=2P(B_n > C(n-1)^p) = 2P(B_1 > C\frac{(n-1)^p}{\sqrt{n}}).$$
So my question is: How can I show that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(B_1 > C\frac{(n-1)^p}{\sqrt{n}}) < \infty$$
for $C>0,p>1/2, B_1 \sim N(0,1)$?

Btw: i'm not even sure whether the sum converges, maybe i have to pick other intervals and not $[n-1,n]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $p>\frac{1}{2}$, we can write $p= \frac{1}{2}+q$ for some $q>0$. Now

$$\frac{(n-1)^p}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}} (n-1)^q \geq \frac{1}{2} (n-1)^q, \qquad n \in \mathbb{N},$$

implies

$$\mathbb{P} \left(B_1 > C \frac{(n-1)^p}{\sqrt{n}} \right) \leq \mathbb{P} \left(B_1 > \frac{C}{2} (n-1)^q\right).$$

Choose $k \in \mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large such that $qk>1$. By the Markov inequality,

$$\mathbb{P}\left(B_1 > \frac{C}{2} (n-1)^q\right) \leq C' \frac{1}{(n-1)^{qk}} \mathbb{E}(|B_1|^k)$$

for $C' := \left( \frac{2}{C} \right)^k$. (Note that we used here that a Gaussian random variable has moments of arbitrary order.) Combining both estimates yields

$$\sum_{n \geq 2} \mathbb{P} \left(B_1 > C \frac{(n-1)^p}{\sqrt{n}} \right) \leq C' \mathbb{E}(|B_1|^k) \sum_{n \geq 2}\frac{1}{(n-1)^{qk}}< \infty.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you think this approach to the problem($B_t/t^p \to 0 a.s.$) is straightforward?

Comment: @danwin Yeah, it is a reasonable approach.